# ConnectionRefusedError at /accounts/register/ when i try to register user

Tags: django, user-registration, activation, connection-refused

guys. i face this error when try to regiter user in my web site. i am beginner. also i do not receive activation email. please see below code. Did you face such issue? How can i solve it? i tried to use different methods, but nothing helped.

in my utilities.py in my app

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.signing import Signer
from bboard.settings import ALLOWED_HOSTS


signer = Signer()

def send_activation_notification(user):
    if ALLOWED_HOSTS:
        host = 'http://' + ALLOWED_HOSTS[0]
    else:
        host = 'http://localhost:8000'
    context = {'user':user, 'host':host, 'sign':signer.sign(user.username)}
    subject = render_to_string('email/activation_letter_subject.txt', context)
    body_text = render_to_string('email/activation_letter_body.txt', context)
    user.email_user(subject, body_text)
```

in views.py

```
    def user_activate(request, sign):
    try:
        username = signer.unsign(sign)
    except BadSignature:
        return render(request, 'main/bad_signature.html')
    user = get_object_or_404(AdvUser, username=username)
    if user.is_activated:
        template = 'main/user_is_activated.html'
    else:
        template = 'main/activation_done.html'
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_activated = True
        user.save()
    return render(request, template)
```

in settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'webmaster@localhost'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
]
```

if i need to provide anything else, please let me know.

i see this error

```
ConnectionRefusedError at /accounts/register/
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine 
actively refused it
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: ConnectionRefusedError
Exception Value:    
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine 
actively refused it
Exception Location: C:\Users\Syubebayev 
Madiyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py, line 796, in 
create_connection
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Syubebayev 
Madiyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Syubebayev Madiyar\\Desktop\\доска объявлений - сайт\\bboard',
 'C:\\Users\\Syubebayev '
 'Madiyar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Syubebayev '
 'Madiyar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Syubebayev '
 'Madiyar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Syubebayev Madiyar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38- 
  32',
 'C:\\Users\\Syubebayev '
 'Madiyar\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Syubebayev '
 'Madiyar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-
```

packages',
'C:\Users\Syubebayev '
'Madiyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-
packages\win32',
'C:\Users\Syubebayev '
'Madiyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
'C:\Users\Syubebayev '
'Madiyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-
packages\Pythonwin']
Server time:   Sat, 03 Oct 2020 10:53:26 +0000

Answer (score 1):

Check if there SMTP running on your localhost at port 25. If it's not, then you need to use a working SMTP settings.

Good first for debugging would be to switch email back end to Console: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#console-backend